# MySQL and PHP search for a string in a table but replace another string

Tags: php, mysql

So basically what i'm trying to do is search inside a table called `"product_description"` find the row `'name'` and inside name search for the string `Energy`.

Lets say i have a product called Energy drink from America. I know how to search for Energy and to replace it:

```
$sql = "UPDATE product_description SET name = REPLACE(name, 'Energy', 'Best Energy')";
```

Is there a way to search for Energy and replace `America` with `Europe`?

Comment: `update ... set foo=replace(...) where foo like '%America%'`?

Comment: In geopolitical terms, **America** cannot be replaced, not by **Europe**. That won't ever happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a WHERE clause with LIKE:

```
UPDATE product_description
    SET name = REPLACE(name, 'America', 'Europe')
        WHERE name LIKE '%Energy%'
```